# Why is my phone only dedup not working?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I created a dedup rule "Phone only", and set the only criteria to Phone, weight 30, and threshold 10. (I also tried 1 and 1). It fails to find duplicate contacts that clearly have matching phone numbers. Kind of at a loss here... the admins are complaining.

CiviCRM 5.29.1
Wordpress Version 5.6

Comment: I just tried this myself on CiviCRM's master branch and it worked no problem.  Could you try logging in at https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and see if it's working there?  If it is, then either there's an issue in that particular version of CiviCRM or there's something specific to your installation (custom extensions etc.)

Comment: do the matching contacts have the same format for the number - eg if one has a space and the other does not are they considered a 'match'/

Comment: The first thing I checked was the phone string. They are identical, with hyphns.

Answer (score 2):

My bad newbie error. The phone numbers matched but one was a household contact and the other an individual and deduping doesn't cross types. Same goes for all our rules.